# How to fix this error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 6220800 bytes in function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Here,i am trying to read lots of image from my root folder and got this type of error.How to fix this issue?

code:

```
def load_images_from_folder_2(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in glob.glob(folder):
        a= cv2.imread(filename)
        #print(a)
        images.append(a)
    return images
```

Return a error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-99a421951aee> in <module>
    168         #videos=f'F:/deepfake_data/train_sample_videos_2/{i}'
    169     root_dir='F:/deepfake_data/train_sample_videos_2/'
--> 170     save_diffs(pairs,root_dir)
    171 

<ipython-input-15-99a421951aee> in save_diffs(pair, root_dir)
    140     frame_2=[]
    141     for n in range(0, len(onlyfiles)):
--> 142         img[n] = cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]) )
    143         frame_2.append(img[n])
    144 

error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-2b5g8ysb\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 6220800 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'
```

Reading images from folder:

```
    mypath="F:/deepfake_data/fake_id.jpg/*.*"
    frame_2=load_images_from_folder_2(mypath)
    print(frame_2)
```

Comment: You will probably need to download 6.22MB of extra RAM.

Answer (score 2):

The error simply states that you **ran out of RAM**, by filling it with images.
In other words, you have too many images in the 'deepfake_data' folder to fit into your PC's temporal memory.

Potential workarounds, given the very limited info provided in the question:

1. **Run your program on a subsets of images** at a time (load N images, process, discard, repeat).
2. Taking same idea to N=1: Process the image as it is being loaded,
   s.t. only a single image is always kept in the memory
3. **Down-sample the images** before appending to the list s.t. each one takes less memory
4. Consider working on **cloud services that has more RAM** than you do, e.g. google Colab.

More info will significantly narrow the answer span.

Answer (score 2):

RAM isn’t really the issue here, the problem is address space. No matter how much RAM you have in your system, the 32 bit, default, version of Python can only access 2GB of RAM.

Try installing the 64 bit versions of Python and OpenCV, which should have enough address space, even if you end up swapping to disc.

Comment: it unlocked my mind; 
thanks